# Row of divs in bottom left corner of parent div

Tags: html, css

I would like the `Div`s labeled button to be in the bottom left corner of the parent `div` instead of where they are now (which is the TOP left corner). Is there a way to do this without using absolute position for each div individually? Here is the HTML and the CSS.

**CSS**

```
.button
{
color: blue;
background-color: green;
width: 200px;
font-size: 20pt;
font-family: "Comic Sans";
position: relative;
float: left;
bottom: 0;
}

.button:hover
{
color: red;
background-color: purple;
 }     
#banner
{
height: 300px;
width: 80%;
background-color: pink;
position: absolute;
left: 10%;
right: 10%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="banner">
        <div class="button" >Home</div>
        <div class="button">About Us</div>
        <div class="button">Contact Us</div>
        <div class="button">Disciplines</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You will get quicker answers if you include a jsFiddle with your question.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Q94Cw/2/

Comment: @melevan: why are you including div inside head section. Read this **[The global structure of an HTML document](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html)**.
try setting `position absolute/fixed` and `bottom` property.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your css:

```
#buttonrow {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Change your markup to include a wrapper div:

```
<div id="banner">

<div id="buttonrow">

<div class="button" >Home</div>
<div class="button">About Us</div>
<div class="button">Contact Us</div>
<div class="button">Disciplines</div>

</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

change your HTML and CSS like this:

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Q94Cw/3/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="banner">
    <div id="container">
        <div class="button" >Home</div>
        <div class="button">About Us</div>
        <div class="button">Contact Us</div>
        <div class="button">Disciplines</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.button
{
color: blue;
background-color: green;
width: 200px;
font-size: 20pt;
font-family: "Comic Sans";
position: relative;
float: left;
bottom: 0;
}

.button:hover
{
color: red;
background-color: purple;
 }     
#banner
{
height: 300px;
width: 80%;
background-color: pink;
position: absolute;
left: 10%;
right: 10%;
}
#container{  /*  add this class  */
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without using `position:absolute`.i.e by setting `margin`.

Try this:

```
.button {
background-color: #008000;
bottom: 0;
color: #0000FF;
float: left;
font-family: "Comic Sans";
font-size: 20pt;
margin-top: 268px;
position: relative;
width: 200px;
}
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/z5UNd/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the nav tag to create horizontal list views.